# Link to specific Customizer section

Tags: themes, wp-admin, theme-customizer

I've got a site with a few extra Customizer sections. Is there a way to link directly to these **so that section open when the page loads**?

Something like `http://mysites.com/wp-admin/customize.php#fonts`

[screenshot http://new.tinygrab.com/96412a96d208cf8ff0cf5803327b2d29e0ca68810e.png](http://new.tinygrab.com/96412a96d208cf8ff0cf5803327b2d29e0ca68810e.png)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As you've already discovered, links to the customizer always start with `/wp-admin/customize.php`.

Append `?autofocus[`**`section`**`] =`**`section_name`** to checkout your section within the customizer. Both parameters (`section` and `section_name`) are registered within your [`customize_register`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_register) hook:

```
$wp_customize->add_section
```

If you can't find the hook, check the HTML markup of the customizer for further information. Both parameters are included within the list:

```
<li id="accordion-section-title_tagline" class="accordion-section control-section control-section-default">
```

Altogether your link may look something like this:

```
admin_url( '/customize.php?autofocus[section]=section_name' );
```

---

These are the links to the default customizer sections in Twenty Twenty WordPress theme:

- Site Identity: `/customize.php?autofocus[section]=title_tagline`
- Colors: `/customize.php?autofocus[section]=colors`
- Theme Options: `/customize.php?autofocus[section]=options`
- Cover Template: `/customize.php?autofocus[section]=cover_template_options`
- Background Image: `/customize.php?autofocus[section]=background_image`
- Menus: `/customize.php?autofocus[panel]=nav_menus`
- Widgets: `/customize.php?autofocus[panel]=widgets`
- Homepage Settings: `/customize.php?autofocus[section]=static_front_page`
- Additional CSS: `/customize.php?autofocus[section]=custom_css`

---

**Where to go from this?**

I often find myself in need of a menu item from *Appearance* within the WordPress admin menu. So maybe this will be helpful for you, too:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse_custom_submenu_page' );
function wpse_custom_submenu_page() {
  add_submenu_page(
    'themes.php',
        __( 'Page title', 'textdomain' ),
        __( 'Menu title', 'textdomain' ),
        'manage_options',
        '/customize.php?autofocus[section]=section_name'
    );
}
```

Comment: This is a good overview +1.

Comment: You can also deep link to the nested sections by appending multiple `autofocus` parameters.
For example, opening the Product Catalog section of WooCommerce.

`customize.php?autofocus[panel]=woocommerce&autofocus[section]=woocommerce_product_catalog`