# How to add css option to Header Image customizer?

Tags: customization, headers, theme-customizer

I have added the [Custom Header](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers) Theme Option to the [Rowling theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/rowling/). It works fine but I want to extend this by adding CSS controls in the customizer for backgound-size, and background-position.

Please can someone enlighten me as to how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I guess you've register your custom header within your child themes `functions.php` file:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-header' );
```

Next [locate the customizer section](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/214491/32946) and append your own setting/controls for the theme customizer. Let's say we want to register `background_position` and `background_size` and store it within an array `custom_header_meta`:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'wpse_customize_custom_header_meta' );
function wpse_customize_custom_header_meta( \WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize ) {

    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'custom_header_meta[background_position]',
        array(
            'default'    => 'left',
            'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
            'type'       => 'option'
        )
    );

    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'custom_header_background_position',
        array(
            'settings' => 'custom_header_meta[background_position]',
            'label'    => __( 'Background position:', 'textdomain' ),
            'section'  => 'header_image',
            'type'     => 'select',
            'choices'  => array(
                'right' => 'right',
                'left'  => 'left'
            )
        )
    );

    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'custom_header_meta[background_size]',
        array(
            'default'    => 'auto',
            'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
            'type'       => 'option'
        )
    );

    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'custom_header_background_size',
        array(
            'settings' => 'custom_header_meta[background_size]',
            'label'    => __( 'Background size:', 'textdomain' ),
            'section'  => 'header_image',
            'type'     => 'select',
            'choices'  => array(
                'auto'    => 'auto',
                'cover'   => 'cover',
                'contain' => 'contain'
            )
        )
    );

}
```

I think you'll get the idea; feel free to play around with this or add further fields. Check the [examples provided in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_register#Examples) for reference.

[image: Customizer controls]

After that we can render the values (stored as array) as well as the WordPress custom header image using [`wp_add_inline_style`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style) function:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_rowling_inline_styles' );
function wpse_rowling_inline_styles() {

    // Get custom header meta from customizer with defaults.
    $default_header_meta = array(
        'background_position' => 'left',
        'background_size'     => 'auto'
    );
    $header_meta = get_option( 'custom_header_meta', $default_header_meta );

    // Render header meta as CSS parameters.
    $header_styles = '';
    foreach ( $header_meta as $key => $val ) {
        $header_styles .= str_replace( '_', '-', $key ) . ':' . $val . ';';
    }

    // Render header image as CSS parameters.
    if ( get_header_image() ) {
        $header_image = get_theme_mod( 'header_image_data' );
        $header_styles .= 'background-image:url(' . $header_image->url . ');';
        $header_styles .= 'width:' . (string) $header_image->width . 'px;';
        $header_styles .= 'height:' . (string) $header_image->height . 'px;';
    }

    // Finally render CSS selector with parameters.
    $custom_css = ".header_image { $header_styles }";

    wp_add_inline_style( 'rowling_style', $custom_css );

}
```

You should now see the styles for the element with the class `header_image` within your source code as well as the rendered version in the live preview besides the rowling customizer.

[image: Customizer styles]

**Further reading:** Also check theme support for [`custom-background`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Backgrounds) as this provides basic support for image styles out of the box (not available in the customizer per default).

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the informative answer.